# Erro com certificado SHA1 (Keystore) - Delphi 10 Berlin

Tags: delphi-10

Estou com um problema. 
Criei um aplicativo no Delphi XE7 ano passado e criei um certificado Keystore. 
Hoje instalei o Delphi 10 Berlin Trial e ao tentar atualizar meu aplicativo ele não está compilando com o certificado correto. 
Já defini em **Project > Options > Provisioning** 
Só que ele não está gerando o APK com o certificado que defini. 
Todos os aplicativos que criei como teste está sendo com o mesmo SHA1, mas não consegui corrigir esse problema.